# How to link a boolean value to the on/off state of a UISwitch?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UISwitch` that I want to control a boolean value in a function I wrote. I looked in the `UISwitch` Type Reference and it listed the property for the on/off state of the switch as `on`. I tried to use this in a action:

```
@IBAction func switchValueChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
        if acsessabilitySwitch.on {
//accessibilitySwitch is the UISwitch in question 
            println("It's True!")
            advice.isInProduction = Bool (true) 
// isInProduction is a attribute of a class
        } else {
            println("It's False!")
            advice.isInProduction = Bool (false)
        }
```

but when I ran it and hit the switch it crashed and didn't print anything.

EDIT:
Here is my ViewController and my custom class files:

BuyingAdviceModel.swift:

```
import Foundation
class videoGameModel{
    var price : Double
    var isInProduction : Bool
    var adviceGiven: String?
    init (isInProduction : Bool, price: Double){
        self.price = price
        self.isInProduction = isInProduction
    }
    func giveAdvice (price:Double, isInProduction:Bool)->(adviceGiven:String){
            if price >= 199.99 {
                var adviceGiven = "Nope, that's too expensive!"
                return adviceGiven
            } else if price <= 99.99{
                if isInProduction == true {
                    var adviceGiven = ("Buy it at GameStop!")
                    return adviceGiven
                } else {
                    var adviceGiven = ("Go look online!")
                    return adviceGiven
                }
            } else {
                var adviceGiven = ("Are you sure you put the info in correctly?")
                return adviceGiven
            }
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var priceTextField: UITextField
    @IBAction func adviceButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let adviceOutputed = advice.adviceGiven!
        adviceLabel.text=adviceOutputed
    }
    @IBAction func viewTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        priceTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

     @IBOutlet var acsessabilitySwitch: UISwitch
     @IBOutlet var adviceLabel: UILabel
     @IBAction func switchValueChanged (sender: UISwitch) {
        advice.isInProduction = sender.on
        println ("It's " + advice.isInProduction.description + "!")
    }
    var advice = videoGameModel (isInProduction: true,price: 0.00)
    func refreshUI(){
        priceTextField.text = String(advice.price)
        adviceLabel.text = ""
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        refreshUI()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Why are you using `acsessabilitySwitch` instead of the `sender` argument? Maybe you forgot to connect its IBOutlet. Also, why are you doing `Bool (true)` instead of just `true`? And lastly, why aren't you just doing `advice.isInProduction = sender.on`?

Answer (score 50):

Add the UISwitch Reference into ViewController.swift file.

```
@IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch 
@IBOutlet var switchState: UILabel
```

then add the target event into the viewdidload method like below

```
mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.switchIsChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

When the switch is flipped the UIControlEventValueChanged event is triggered and the stateChanged method will be called.

```
func switchIsChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    if mySwitch.on {
        switchState.text = "UISwitch is ON"
    } else {
        switchState.text = "UISwitch is OFF"
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
func switchIsChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    if mySwitch.isOn {
        switchState.text = "UISwitch is ON"
    } else {
        switchState.text = "UISwitch is OFF"
    }
}
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
@objc func switchIsChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    if mySwitch.isOn {
        switchState.text = "UISwitch is ON"
    } else {
        switchState.text = "UISwitch is OFF"
    }
}
```

find brief tutorial in https://sourcefreeze.com/uiswitch-tutorial-using-swift-in-ios8/

Answer (score 22):

Succinctness, even parsimony, is important in coding style.  Try this:

```
@IBAction func switchValueChanged (sender: UISwitch) {
  advice.isInProduction = sender.on
  print ("It's \(advice.isInProduction)!")
}
```

In your original code, you likely crashed because `acsessabilitySwitch` or `advice` are unbound (have values of `nil`).

[Updated - replaced `println` with `print`]

Comment: I implemented this code in and it still crashed when I hit the switch. I will post the full code in the question.

Comment: Upvote for the sentence ***"Succinctness, even parsimony, is important in coding style"*** and for the essential implementation.

Answer (score 7):

For swift 3

[image]

```
@IBAction func switchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        print(sender.isOn)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Drag and drop UISwitch from Object Library-

@IBOutlet-

```
@IBOutlet weak var myswitch: UISwitch!
```

@IBAction-

```
@IBAction func onAllAccessory(sender: UISwitch) {

        if myswitch.on == true{
            onCall()
        }
        if myswitch.on == false{
            offCall()
        }
    }
```

Your function-

```
func onCall(){
        print("On is calling")
    }
    func offCall(){
        print("Off is calling")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3, is chance.

```
if mySwitch.on
```

to

```
if mySwitch.isOn
```

[myprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR9Pz.png)

Answer (score 2):

No need for extra boolean.
use this :

```
if mySwitch.isOn {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

this is an always up to date boolean for switch state, so **NO NEED** to create your own variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change the switch you can use

```
mySwitch.on = true
```

to set it to "on"
or

```
mySwitch.off == false
```

to set it to "off"

Or if you want to get the value you can use

```
let myBool = mySwitch.on
```

If the switch is powered on the value will be true, otherwise false.

You can also make an action called valueChanged (to get or update the value whenever the switch value is changed)

```
@IBAction func valueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    // some code
}
```

You can do this by select the dualView... view and ctrl drag from your switch to you view controller and choose action, and value changed if that's not already selected.

Comment: Do not answer if you dont understand the question