# How can I save the SwichButton setting?

Tags: ios, swift

I've got 4 SwichButton, this is standard to Off.

How can I save the setting when a switch button is set to on ?

I have this:

```
        @IBAction func SwitchNofic(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    let switchTag = sender.tag

    if (switchTag == 1) && (sender.isOn == true){
        print("1")
        createNoficationMorgen()
    }else if (switchTag == 2) && (sender.isOn == true){
        print("2")
        createNoficationMittag()
    }else if (switchTag == 3) && (sender.isOn == true){
        print("3")
        createNoficationAbend()
    }else if (switchTag == 4) && (sender.isOn == true){
        print("4")
        createNoficationNacht()
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you can look this link it would help you.
[Releated Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714921/how-to-link-a-boolean-value-to-the-on-off-state-of-a-uiswitch)

Comment: Try something. Apply the answers that you just got two hours ago. It's the same fundamental problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you want to save it just for the time the app is alive.

Just use a boolean variable so you know what is on and what is not, also each switchButton has a property **isOn**.

If you want it to be persistant try **UserDefaults**.

**Swift 4**

To save permanently :

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: “isDarkModeKey”)
```

To retrieve (this should be called in viewDidAppear):

```
let isDarkModeEnabled = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: “isDarkModeKey”)

if isDarkModeEnabled {
   mySwicth.setOn(true, animated : false)
   //set the background to dark
} else {
   mySwicth.setOn(false, animated : false)
   //set the background to white
}
```